# How can I search only in specifics object.keys in a array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find, salesforce-lightning

I have the following array:

```
arr = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Something', code: 'A33', number: '67', house: 'St55' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Another', code: '55', number: '004', house: 'ES' },
  { id: '3', name: 'One more', code: 'DAE', number: '003', house: 'R5' },
];
```

I'm using the function bellow ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143107/string-search-with-all-fields-of-array-of-objects)) for a search bar to search all fields of array of objects (`arr`) depends on the user inputs (`value`):

```
function findInValues(arr, value) {
  value = String(value).toLowerCase();
  return arr.filter(o =>
    Object.entries(o).some(entry =>
      String(entry[1]).toLowerCase().includes(value)
    )
  );
}
```

But to resolve my case, the function would can search only on the keys `name` and `house`, the search must ignore `id`,`code` and `number`.

**For example:**

```
value = 55

Result = [
      { id: '1', name: 'Something', code: 'A33', number: '67', house: 'St55' }
     ];
```

What should I do in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can destructure the keys `id`, `code` and `number` that you want to ignore from the object you're filtering and then grab the remaining object without these properties using the rest syntax `...o`. You can then use the same code that you're currently using to search the `o` object. Note that below, I have also changed `Object.entries()` to be just `Object.values()` as your code isn't using the key from the entry array:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Something', code: 'A33', number: '67', house: 'St55' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Another', code: '55', number: '004', house: 'ES' },
  { id: '3', name: 'One more', code: 'DAE', number: '003', house: 'R5' },
];

function findInValues(arr, value) {
  value = String(value).toLowerCase();
  return arr.filter(({id, code, number, ...o}) =>
    Object.values(o).some(val =>
      String(val).toLowerCase().includes(value)
    )
  );
}

console.log(findInValues(arr, 55));
```

Otherwise, if you know the keys you want to search (ie: `name` and `house`), then you can check those explicitly:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Something', code: 'A33', number: '67', house: 'St55' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Another', code: '55', number: '004', house: 'ES' },
  { id: '3', name: 'One more', code: 'DAE', number: '003', house: 'R5' },
];

function findInValues(arr, value) {
  value = String(value).toLowerCase();
  const search = ['name', 'house'];
  return arr.filter(o => search.some(key => o[key].toLowerCase().includes(value)));
}

console.log(findInValues(arr, 55));
```

Comment: Thanks! I had only to change the end to `String(o[key]).toLowerCase().includes(value)`

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version! :)

```
function findInValues(arr, value) {
    value = String(value).toLowerCase();
    return arr.filter(({
            name,
            house
        }) =>
        (name.toLowerCase() == value || house.toLowerCase() == value)
    );
}
```